# Change "<path>" value with different string depends on last line

Tags: sed, awk, tr

Change `"<path>"` value with different string depends on last line. In that case when see in the last line "*" to replace `"<path>"` with `"ls -lrt"` and to separate the `"*"` from the last line when see slash for anything else with `"find"`.

Text file:

```
<path>/etc/inet.d/*.conf
<path>/etc/rc/*
<path>/etc/rc*
```

Expect View:

```
find /etc/inet.d/*.conf
ls -lrt /etc/rc/ *
ls -lrt /etc/rc*
```

Comment: Try to think how others should understand you post

Comment: My corollary to the postulate by @hek2mgl: Wut?

Comment: @twalberg What does this mean? I just tried to point to the fact, that I'm not understand the question, while I'm willing to help. You both, OP and twalberg should try to enhance your communication skills!

Comment: I think you mean **the last character of each line** , not last line!

Comment: @hek2mgl I was agreeing with you... My initial response to the question was literally "Wut?!?"...

Comment: @twalberg I think we have a communication problem. This may being caused by my poor english knowledge. I can only say that I'm not `wütend` :)

Comment: @hek2mgl imo he doesn'n mean German, but `A "leet" word for what` :)

Comment: Not everyone's first language is english...  Don't be so harsh!

Comment: Hi All, Excuse em for incorrect explanation, actually the answer of @Kent helps me that what I want ... KUDOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean last character of each line, not last line!

if it is right, check this out:

```
awk '{if($0~/\*$/)sub(/<path>/,"ls -lrt ");else sub(/<path>/,"find ")}7' file
```

with your data:

```
kent$  echo "<path>/etc/inet.d/*.conf
<path>/etc/rc/*
<path>/etc/rc*"|awk '{if($0~/\*$/)sub(/<path>/,"ls -lrt ");else sub(/<path>/,"find ")}7' 
find /etc/inet.d/*.conf
ls -lrt /etc/rc/*
ls -lrt /etc/rc*
```

Comment: +1 for your effort on a hardly understandable question. For me currently it is likely that this is the right answer